# How can we write a `__getitem__` method which accepts any iterable as input, and chains the items together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, containers, operator-overloading

How can we turn `cookiejar[(1, 2, 3)]` into `cookiejar[1][2][3]`?

#### What is the desired behavior?

The following two pieces of code (`LEFT CODE` and `RIGHT CODE`) should do the same thing when calling `__getitem__`

```py
+----------------------+--------------------------+
|      LEFT CODE       |        RIGHT CODE        |
+----------------------+--------------------------+
| cjar   = CookieJar() | cjar     = CookieJar()   |
| result = cjar[index] | indices  = [1, 2, 3]     |
|                      | indices  = iter(index)   |
|                      | index    = next(it)      |
|                      | result = cjar[index][it] |
+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

More examples are shown below. The code in the column at left should exhibit the same outward behavior as the code in the column at right.

```python
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[1][2][3]       |  cookie_jar[(1, 2, 3)]        |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[x][y]          |  cookie_jar[(x, y)]           |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[99]            |  cookie_jar[(99,)]            |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[99]            |  cookie_jar[[[[99]]]          |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[1][2][3]       |  cookie_jar[1, 2][3]          |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[1][2][3]       |  cookie_jar[[1, [2]], [3]]    |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[1][2][3]       |  cookie_jar[1, 2, 3]          |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[3][11][19]     |  cookie_jar[3:20:8]           |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  cookie_jar[3][11][19]     |  cookie_jar[range(3, 20, 8)]  |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

#### What is the difference between a single key/index and a container of keys or indices?

If you try to convert `table["hello world"]` into `table['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']... ['l']['d']` you can easily create an infinite loop.

The following code never stops running:

```python
def go_to_leaf(root):
    while hasattr(root, '__iter__'):
        root = iter(root)
        root = next(root)

# BEGIN INFINITE LOOP!
left_most_leaf = go_to_leaf("hello world")
```

Should use something like this instead:

```py
def is_leaf(cls, knode):
    """
        returns true if the input is a valid key (index)
        into the container.

        returns false if the input is a container of keys
        or is an invalid key  
    """
    if hasattr(knode, "__iter__"):
        return str(knode) == "".join(str(elem) for elem in knode)
    else: # not iterable
        return True
```

If you had a 3-dimentional table of numbers it would not matter if x-y coordinates were inside of a single tuple or list, or used separately.

```py
element = table[2][7][3]
element = table[2, 7, 3]
element = table[(2, 7, 3)]
```

Comment: A function doesn't know how its result is going to be used. So `cookiejar[1]` can't return a different result depending on whether it's going to be further indexed with `[2]`.

Comment: @Barmar We don't need to know if `root[1]` will be further indexed or not further indexed. in a tree application `root[1]` returns a child of the root node in a tree. For `root[1][2]` at first we have a child of the root node, but in the end we have a grandchild of the root node. It does not matter if we write `root[1]` and quit or write `root[1][2]`. Likewise if you have a matrix of numbers `mat[3]` returns row number 3. if you want the value in row 3 and column 8, then we have `mat[3][8]` The row object does not know if it will be further indexed into or it the end-user wanted the whole row.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking about. The question is too long, I didn't read most of it.

Comment: @Barmar it is long question, yes. I wish I was more concise. I recommend reading everything except the code blocks. Then go back and read the blocks of code if you are still interested.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to turn `cookiejar[(1, 2, 3)]` into `cookiejar[1][2][3]`? The latter is the normal way to index multiple dimensions, you want to be able to do it with an iterable instead.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am mostly asking how to turn `cookiejar[(1, 2, 3)]` into `cookiejar[1][2][3]` However, we could also have `cookiejar[(1, 2)][3]` or `cookiejar[(1, (2, ((3,),)))]`

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Trying to flatten the data ahead of time is a step in the wrong direction, because it loses information. Most of this post is your own incomplete thoughts about how to solve the problem - which are *not necessary to understand the question*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I spend 99% of my time fixing compiler errors and 1% of my time programming. One of the most common problems is that I put `(x, y)` coordinates into a function as `foo(x, y)` when it is supposed to be `foo([x, y])`. I write `table[x, y]` when it is supposed to be `table[x][y]` or I write `table[x][y]` when it is supposed to be `table[x, y]` This is nightmare when it comes to libraries for manipulating matricies or tables such as ***numpy*** or ***pandas*** I am tired of reading compiler errors because I used the `[]` operator differently that how I was supposed to.

Comment: I don't need an explanation of why this would be useful. I already attempted a solution.

Comment: Seems to me your use-case can be solved with some type-hinting and a util implementing Ruby's [Hash#dig()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) and [Array#dig()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-dig), in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic idea

Instead of making a separate container type, make a *view* for containers. The semantics are:

- A view instance tracks some iterable (which might be an element of some other iterable). For simplicity, we won't bother checking whether it's a proper container type or lazily evaluated.
- When the view is indexed with a value of a non-iterable type, it indexes into the container with that value.
- When the view is indexed with a value of an iterable type, it repeats the indexing for each element in that value.
- If the result of the indexing is iterable, the result is a view around that iterable. Otherwise, the result is the value itself.

It can be implemented quite simply:

```
class View:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        result = self._data
        # We can't easily distinguish a `TypeError` due to `indices`
        # being a non-iterable, from a `TypeError` due to reaching a 
        # leaf in the data prematurely. So we explicitly check first.
        try:
            iter(indices)
        except TypeError:
            result = result[indices]
        else:
            for i in indices:
                result = result[i]
        # Now decide whether to wrap the result
        try:
            iter(result)
        except TypeError:
            return result
        else:
            return View(result)
```

As a refactoring, we could use `__new__` rather than `__init__` so that the argument is returned unchanged if it isn't iterable. That prevents explicitly creating bad Views, and can also simplify the `__getitem__` logic:

```
class View:
    def __new__(cls, data):
        try:
            iter(data)
            result = object.__new__(cls)
            result._data = data
        except TypeError:
            result = data
        return result

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        result = self._data
        try:
            iter(indices)
        except TypeError:
            result = result[indices]
        else:
            for i in indices:
                result = result[i]
        return View(result)
```

### Special cases

There are two problems with this result compared to the specification:

1. `slice` objects are not actually iterable. We want to interpret `myview[3:20:8]` as if it were actually being indexed with the values described by that *range*, in sequence. Fortunately, it is trivial to convert a `slice` into the corresponding `range` object with the same `start`, `stop` and `step`.

   However, we need to complain if the `start` or `stop` are unspecified, since otherwise the semantics don't make any sense; and we have to keep in mind that ranges don't accept `None` as a step value (`slice`s treat it as equivalent to `1`). Finally, we have to accept that negative values will not index from the end, since again it will be far too difficult to interpret what should happen for all the corner cases.
2. Strings (and possibly other types) *are* iterable, and the elements are themselves non-empty strings - thus they can be indexed into arbitrarily many times. We need to special-case these in order for them to work as leaf nodes.

We need helper logic to treat strings as if they were not iterable. It should apply to construction, too (since otherwise we could make a totally useless `View` instance from a string). We don't want that logic to handle slices, because `View(slice(0))` should give us the original `slice` back, not a `range`.

With some refactoring, we get:

```
def _make_range(a_slice):
    start, stop, step = a_slice.start, a_slice.stop, a_slice.step
    if start is None or stop is None:
        raise ValueError('start and stop must be defined to convert to range')
    return range(start, stop, 1 if step is None else step)

def _non_string_iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(data)
        return not isinstance(obj, str)
    except TypeError:
        return False

class View:
    def __new__(cls, data):
        if _non_string_iterable(data):
            result = object.__new__(cls)
            result._data = data
            return result
        return data

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        result = self._data
        if isinstance(indices, slice):
            indices = _make_range(indices)
        if _non_string_iterable(indices):
            for i in indices:
                result = result[i]
        else:
            result = result[indices]
        return View(result)
```

Comment: Your definition `def __getitem__(self, indices)` forces `__getitem__` to accept only one argument. We want `__getitem__` to be variadic. In a function call to a 3-dimentional table, we could write, `table[1, 68, 2]` I recommend writing `def __getitem__(self, *indices)` since then we can write `table[1, 68, 2]`. If we do things your original way, then we have to write something like `table[(1, 68, 2)]` or `table[[1, 68, 2]]`. That is, we could input a tuple or a list into `__getitem__`, but not more than one argument. Ideally, `__getitem__` can accept any number of arguments.

Comment: `try: iter(index)` is not a good way to check to see if index is a leaf node. As you pointed out, strings are infinitely index-able. For example, `next(iter(next(iter("A")))) == "A"`. Also, if `index` is a string of 1 or more characters the following is an infinite loop: `while hasattr(index, "__iter__"): index = next(iter(index))`. Strings aren't the only class that does that. there is a `bytes` class whose children's children's children are always iterable. In my original question, I explained that the test for leaf nodes is `str(knode) == "".join(str(elem) for elem in knode)`.

Comment: We should test `str(parent) == "".join(str(child) for child in parent)` instead of testing `hasattr(index, "__iter__")` or testing `isinstance(index, str)`

Comment: "Your definition `def __getitem__(self, indices)` forces `__getitem__` to accept only one argument. We want `__getitem__` to be variadic." No, that isn't how `__getitem__` works. If you make a call like `x[3, 4, 5]`, then `__getitem__` will be passed *a tuple* of those values, not separate arguments - it is identical to `x[(3, 4, 5)]`. `__getitem__` will only ever receive one argument when called internally by Python.

Comment: "`try: iter(index)` is not a good way to check to see if index is a leaf node." That's why I built a wrapper in the next step. `bytes` does not work like that in 3.x - indexing into a `bytes` gives an integer instead. I see the logic of your test and you can easily swap it in to `_non_string_iterable`.

Comment: You are right. I thought that `__getitem__` was like other python class methods regarding a variable number of input arguments. I thought we needed to write an asterisk in the function defintion: `def __getitem__(self, *indicies)`. I see now; `__getitem__` always bundles the arguments together into a single tuple. Sorry about that; that was my mistake. Your answer is a good one.

Comment: There is a bit of history here: Python used to use a separate `__getslice__` to handle slicing vs. indexing, which would receive `start`, `stop`, `step` as separate arguments. I think originally there wasn't a separate `slice` class to represent the values, but `__getslice__` was supported for a while after for backwards compatibility.

Comment: (From a brief search: `__getslice__` was supposed to be deprecated since 2.0, and also didn't support extended slices; but it didn't actually get removed until 3.0.)

Answer (score 1):

Combining [`collapse()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#collapse) and a Python version of [`dig()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#dig), with special `slice` handling, reproduces your input table of examples:

```py
from more_itertools import collapse  # or implement this yourself
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


def dig(collection, *keys):
    """Dig into nested subscriptable objects, e.g. dict and list, i.e JSON."""
    curr = collection
    for k in keys:
        if curr is None:
            break

        if not hasattr(curr, '__getitem__') or isinstance(curr, str):
            raise TypeError(f'cannot dig into {type(curr)}')

        try:
            curr = curr[k]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            curr = None

    return curr


def what_you_wanted(collection, *keys):  # If I understood you correctly
    slic = keys[0] if len(keys) == 1 and isinstance(keys[0], slice) else None
    dig_keys = range(slic.stop)[slic] if slic else collapse(keys)
    return dig(collection, *dig_keys)


def test_getitem_with(*keys):
    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.__getitem__.returns = mock
    what_you_wanted(mock, *keys)
    print(mock.mock_calls)


test_getitem_with((1, 2, 3))
test_getitem_with(('x', 'y'))
test_getitem_with((99,))
test_getitem_with([[[99]]])
test_getitem_with((1, 2), 3)
test_getitem_with(([1, [2]], [3]))
test_getitem_with(1, 2, 3)
test_getitem_with(slice(3, 20, 8))
test_getitem_with(range(3, 20, 8))
```

Prints:

```
[call.__getitem__(1),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(2),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(3)]
[call.__getitem__('x'), call.__getitem__().__getitem__('y')]
[call.__getitem__(99)]
[call.__getitem__(99)]
[call.__getitem__(1),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(2),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(3)]
[call.__getitem__(1),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(2),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(3)]
[call.__getitem__(1),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(2),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(3)]
[call.__getitem__(3),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(11),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(19)]
[call.__getitem__(3),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__(11),
 call.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__(19)]
```

For completion, could define a collection object (or View) that implements `__getitem__()` using `what_you_wanted()`.